# parent-child-grandchild data in one multidimentional array using php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, parent-child

Here’s my problem.
I have 3 tables in my database. Collections, Boxsets and CDs.
These tables have parent-child-grandchild relations as following:

A Collection has one or more Boxsets

A Boxset has one or more CDs

I created the following columns to each table:

**Collections**

- collection_id - collection_title

**Boxsets**

- boxset_id - boxset_title - collection_id

**CDs**

- cd_id - cd_title - boxset_id

I am trying to get all available data and structure these data in a multidimensional array in order to display my data as follows: 
-Collection 1
—Boxset1
—-CD 1
—-CD 2
—Boxset 2
—-CD 1
...
-Collections 2
....

However getting all data in one array looks impossible without adding a "collection_id" field on 'cds' table. My solution so far is creating two arrays (a collections-boxsets array and a boxsets-cds array) as follows:

```
$collections = $this->collection_model->get_all_collections();
  foreach($collections->result_array() as $row){
   $arrayCollections[$row['collection_id']] = $row;
  }  
  $boxsets = $this->boxset_model->get_all_boxsets();
  foreach($boxsets->result_array() as $row){
   $arrayCollections[$row['collection_id']]['boxsets'][] = $row;
  }
  foreach($boxsets->result_array() as $row){
   $arrayBoxset[$row['boxset_id']] = $row;
  }  
  $cds = $this->cd_model->get_all_cds();
  foreach($cds->result_array() as $row){
   $arrayBoxset[$row['boxset_id']]['cds'][] = $row;
  }
  foreach($arrayCollections as $collections){
   echo '-'.$collections['collection_title'].'<br />'; 
   foreach($collections['boxsets'] as $boxset){
    echo '--'.$boxset['boxset_title'].'<br />';
    foreach($arrayBoxset[$boxset['boxset_id']]['cds'] as $cd){
     echo '---'.$cd['title'].'<br />';
    }
   }  
  }
```

Any suggestions to optimize this?

Comment: it would be better to make a single query from CDs or from collections?
If all these tables are related, you can use INNER JOINS. At the end using a single function in the model that shows all the data on the CD by row.

Comment: if i undestand right, what you suggest will join all relative data to CDs. This would not provide me however a hierarchical structure which is the main point in my question.

Comment: You could use GROUP_CONCAT () (if you use mysql) for example, when you need all the CDs of each collection per line

Comment: what i need is my data structured as parent-child-grandchild (collection - collection_boxsets - boxset_cds).

Comment: i changed the description of my problem for better understanding and also posted my solution so far. If i can get the specific structure with a single query can you provide mw an example?